# Oracle Update Query missing SET keyword - ORA97100 & ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle

Im getting a confusing **"ORA97100 missing SET keyword"** error when trying to run this simple UPDATE statement, although the "set" keyword is there:

```
UPDATE CURRENT_LOAD as ac
SET ac.LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ac.LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP IS NULL;
```

I also tried, which gives "**invalid identifier ORA-00904 AC.LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP"**

```
UPDATE CURRENT_LOAD ac
SET ac.load_start_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ac.load_start_timestamp IS NULL;
```

I further tried, which gives again **"invalid identifier ORA-00904 CURRENT_LOAD.LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP"**

```
UPDATE CURRENT_LOAD 
SET CURRENT_LOAD.load_start_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE CURRENT_LOAD.load_start_timestamp IS NULL;
```

This is really odd since the attribute "LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP" is actually defined in my table , see the "CURRENT_LOAD" table DDL below:

```
 CREATE TABLE "CURRENT_LOAD"
   (
  "LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP with TIME ZONE, 
    "CONTRACT_NO" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PROJECT_DEFINITION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "MASTER_CONTRACT_NO" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "Sac_CONTRACT_NO" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
);
```

Any well thought advise will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the last version you're missing a dot between the table and column names in the where clause. `CURRENT_LOADload_start_timestamp` -> `CURRENT_LOAD.load_start_timestamp` Change that and it should work. Also, you shouldn't need to specfiy the bale name in the set and where clauses. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2607c/1

Comment: @AryanNaim - the initial problem was the use of `AS` before the table alias - this is not allowed. Secondly - if you're getting an ORA-00904 when trying to access LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP, and the column exists with that exact name, then it appears you don't have the appropriate permissions to use this column. You'll have to talk to your DBA to see if you can get a more detailed explanation of this. Best of luck.

Comment: Both the second and third query (now that you've corrected the missing period) are syntactically valid.  See this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7527c/3  If you're getting an error, something about the query you're actually running (or the table you're actually running against) is different from the table and query you posted here.  The fact that you're using case-sensitive identifiers makes me suspect that in your actual code you've inadvertently created a case-sensitive identifier that you're trying to reference in your `UPDATE` without enclosing it in double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the `UPDATE` statement without table alias `ac` like

```
UPDATE CURRENT_LOAD
SET LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP IS NULL;
```

Also, the problem is with `AS` before table alias. Your `UPDATE` statement should look like

```
UPDATE CURRENT_LOAD ac
SET ac.LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ac.LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP IS NULL;
```

See [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm) for more information.

Comment: I tried that , but I got error "invalid identifier ORA-00904 LOAD_START_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: @AryanNaim, that can't be possible. Here's a proof http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e061.

Comment: The syntax diagram you've posted is for Java DB (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), a database product that Oracle Corp owns, not the syntax diagram for the Oracle database.  You cannot have an `AS` after the table name in Oracle.

Comment: @Rahul: quite possible, if the user doesn't have SELECT permissions on the column. In addition, Oracle does allow table correlation names (aliases) to be used in an UPDATE statement - [see this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1862b/3). Share and enjoy.

Comment: @JustinCave, Ahh!! didn't recognized that but even in oracle UPDATE syntax (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm) I don't see it uses table alias in SET statement which makes the answer correct I believe.

Comment: @Rahul - The actual `UPDATE` statement that you posted is fine (as are 2 of the 3 `UPDATE` statements in the original question).  The syntax diagram, however, is incorrect because it shows `AS` as an optional piece of syntax (true in Java DB) when it is not permitted in Oracle.

Comment: @JustinCave I am pretty confused from what you saying. See this fiddle with table alias and I got exact same error as OP http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e061

Comment: @Rahul - That fiddle does not have a table alias.  This fiddle (the same one I posted in the answer comments http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7527c/3) shows that 2 of the 3 statements from the original question are syntactically valid.  One of those options is using a table alias.

Comment: @JustinCave, absolutely correct. The problem was with `AS` before table alias. Thanks for pointing that.